# Sharing the native pointer between managed wrappers in C++/CLI

Tags: pointers, visual-c++, c++-cli, interop, handle

Say I have two native (unmanaged) classes `A` and `B`. I create a managed wrapper around `A` as

```
public ref class AWrapper
{
    A *a;
    protected:
        // Finalizer that frees pointer a
    public:
        // Destructor that calls the finalizer
        // Wrapped methods
}
```

Similarly for `B` to create `BWrapper`.

Now assume one of the methods of `B` has signature `void (A*)`. **How do I wrap such a method?**

In my understanding, the wrapper method should have the signature `void (AWrapper^)` in this situation, but how do I get the `A*` from `AWrapper^` then? I'm hoping there's a better way than to make all the native pointers (`A*`, `B*`) which need to be consumed by other classes have `internal` visibility.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is that C++ `public ref class AWrapper`?

Comment: @Pi Sorry, just changed the tag to visual-c++ instead of the "suggested" c++.

Comment: Why do you need access to `A*` form wrapper `AWrapper^`? In my opinion `AWrapper^` should exposed API for higher level software layer created in .NET. In such a scenarion there is no need to have access to the `A*`. Also maintenance of the `A*` should be performed inside `AWrapper^`.

Comment: @Slawomir One of B's method is a consumer of A*. Not my choice since that's part of the library I'm trying to create a wrapper for.

Comment: @rahul1210: I don't know your architecture but perhaps the better idea is to create one wrapper around `A` and `B` class?